# Cannot see Content Type in Orchard

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I am running Orchard 1.6 and have the following problem when setting up a Site of either template Blog or Core.

I go to the dashboard and go to the Content menu item on the left.  There is no Content Type menu item only Content.

All training videos seem to get this straight away, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the modules (there's a link in the left menu) and enable `ContentTypes` feature.